# Python file rename program - abspath issue

Tags: python, shutil

In the below code, I cannot get the renamed file to save in the same directory as the original file being /Users/xxx/Documents/Dates

I'm looking for help to explain why?

```
#! usr/bin/env python3
# renameDates.py - Renames filenames with America MM-DD-YYYY date format
# to European DD-MM-YYYY 

import shutil, os, re

#create a regex that matches files with the America date format. 
datePattern = re.compile(r'''^(.*?) # all text before the date
        ((0|1)?\d)-                 #one or two digits for the month
        ((0|1|2|3)?\d)-             #one or two digits for the day 
        ((19|20)\d\d)               #four digits for the year 
        (.*?)$                      #all text after the date 
        ''', re.VERBOSE)

for amerFilename in os.listdir('/Users/xxx/Documents/Dates'):
    mo = datePattern.search(amerFilename)
    if mo == None:
        continue

    beforePart = mo.group(1)
    monthPart = mo.group(2)
    dayPart = mo.group(4)
    yearPart = mo.group(6)
    afterPart = mo.group(8)
    euroFilename = beforePart + dayPart + '-' + monthPart + '-' + yearPart + afterPart
    absWorkingDir = os.path.abspath('./Dates')
    amerFilename = os.path.join(absWorkingDir, amerFilename)
    print('Renaming "%s" to :%s:...' % (amerFilename, euroFilename))
    shutil.move(amerFilename, euroFilename) #uncomment after testing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pulling amerFilename files from a specific directory ('/Users/xxx/Documents/Dates') in your `for` statement. But then you move them to a euroFilename which is defined as a filename, but not defined as within that same specific directory.

If you change your last line to:

```
shutil.move(amerFilename, os.path.join('/Users/xxx/Documents/Dates', euroFilename))
```

...do you get what you want?

Comment: Hi Pedro, if this answer solved your problem, could you please accept it (by clicking the check mark on the left side)?

Comment: Yes this helped handle it. Thanks, I am just starting out programming you explanation was great.